# Making new column based on date with variable year

Tags: sql, postgresql

As topic is saying, it all should apply to dates with variable year.

I would like to make a new column (called which_part for example) saying if the date (in this case date is in "*sil.sales_invoice_date*") is between 1st of january to 30th of june - which should say H1 (half 1) and else is H2 (between 1st of july to end of the year).

I've tried doing something like that with *convert*

```
SELECT
sil.sales_invoice_date AS "Distributor Invoice Date",
CONVERT(sil.sales_invoice_date, @year + '-01-01') AS [start year],
CONVERT(sil.sales_invoice_date, @year + '-06-30') AS [end year],
```

It doesn't work at all and I can't write *[half year]* in there.

I've also tried to do it by using

```
case sil.sales_invoice_date between
```

But I don't really know how to format it to work with variable year.

Comment: Put those CONVERT's in the select list instead of the from clause.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  The `convert()`s don't look like Postgres syntax.  Sample data and desired support would really help.

Comment: Sorry it's my bad, it is select in right code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have date in format dd.mm.yyyy
Try this

```
Case when substr(sil.sales_invoice_date,1,5) between '01.01' and '30.06' then 'H1'
else 'H2'
end as which_part;
```

Comment: substring seems to not work for me, I don't know why. Maybe worth to mark that I operate on postgres db